# Platform Windows , the code give back Linux, debugging app on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i've a really strange situation.
I'm developing with xamarin a mobile application on Windows 10 Pro 21H2 64bit, i've also tried on 22H2 64bit machine.

When the debug reach this code it give me back OSPlatform.Linux.....

```
            var OSVersion_dep = Environment.OSVersion.Platform;

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))

                return OperatingSystem.Windows;

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))

                return OperatingSystem.Unix;

            if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))

                return OperatingSystem.MacOSX;
```

The motivation is the one below:

**because the android os is linux, and your code is running in a android emulator (linux virtual machine)**

OK,

but the others who run the application on Windows OS, how do they debug the code, if they don't use the Android emulator (Linux VM)?

What I mean is, how do others who use a wrapper (like Tesseract) on Windows systems that need to load dynamically libraries (with extension .dll for Windows OS) related to the OS system does test it?

If then in debug the pointed system is always Unix (with libraries extension .os for Unix OS)?

Excuse me, but i'm new to the develop of Application on mobile.

I've seen that on VS2019 there are two option in the Visual Studio Installer, perhaps i've installed the wrong one (the one in yellow color), i've to install the one circled in red, or i've to install Android Studio?

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Many thank in advance.

Comment: use [DeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios) to check the runtime OS

Comment: You've installed the correct workload (Xamarin).

Comment: Re-reading your question, I am not clear what your goal is. You mention "dynamically load libraries". Is that what you need to do?